# layout "include" feature doesn't support layout_gravity property?

Tags: android, layout, include

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, android:layout_gravity will be always ignored? That's really bad for code reusability...
It seems like layout_margin doesn't supported either.

And here is view1.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/updater_background" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No I disn't. It seems like Android bug.

Comment: It is still not working (Android 4.0.3) ! Have you found a work around to use the **layout_gravity** attribute for **include** ? Even though it should work as stated [HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) that any android:layout_* attribute can be used with the <include /> tag.

Comment: I never runned into this issue again. You workaround seems nice tough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two years later, the bug still exists ! Even though **ALL android:layout_*** attributes should be supported by the  tag, the **android:layout_gravity** attribute is not (which kind of is a big disadvantage for layout re-usability).

The work around that I am currently using is to set the layout margin programmatically as follows :

```java
( (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) includedView.getLayoutParams () ).gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

OR for a **FrameLayout** as parent for example :

```
( (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) includedView.getLayoutParams () ).gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

---

EDIT :

I have also found that the **android:layout_gravity** attribute is applied for the **include** tag **IF** it (The **include** tag) has **layout_width** and **layout_height** tags !

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. It really works this way in XML

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be solved by inserting weighted layout

For example

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.sample.SampleActivity">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <--Some other Views-->

</LinearLayout>


<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/my_awesome_layout"
    />
```

The LinearLayout can be replaced with Space, if you don't want any component.

Answer (score 1):

This Android Studio error told me what the problem was "Layout parameter layout_gravity ignored unless both layout_width and layout_height are also specified on  tag".

Add layout_width and layout_height and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html states all the layout_ attributes are supported.

In your case centering in a horizontal `LinearLayout` probably has no effect. Try another layout other parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry for inconvinience, there should be android:layout_gravity="center_vertical". It's work just fine without include tag, but doesn't work with it. I checked it on Android 1.5 device

Comment: can you also post the referenced .xml files pls?

Comment: The link is broken. I believe it is [THIS](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/) now. It also states that **ALL android:layout_** attributes *should* supported by the **include** tag, and still **android:layout_gravity** is not working.